# You can even avoid the limit for maximum CPU time by replacing Apex code and record-change processes with before-save updates in flows

Tags: visual-workflow

In this maintenance module:

- [Get Hands-on With Flow Before-Save Trigger When Certain Record Changes are Made](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform-app-builder-certification-maintenance-winter-21/get-handson-with-flow-before-save-trigger-when-certain-record-changes-are-made)

It states

> You can even avoid the limit for maximum CPU time on the Salesforce servers by replacing Apex code and record-change processes with before-save updates in flows.

Are they saying that we reduce the chance of hitting the `maximum CPU limit` because `Before-Save` flows are **10x** quicker, or, are they staying the `maximum CPU limit` does not apply to `Before-Save` flows?

An official response from Salesforce would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation, **Before-Save** flows are quicker than using a record-change process of process builder. Maximum CPU limit will have to apply to these **Before-Save** flows; documentation does not suggest otherwise. The documentation suggests that Before-Save flows are to be preferred instead of record-change process of process builder or **Apex** code.

The documentation: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_before_save_updates.htm

Comment: Please could you link to the documentation that explicitly states this? thanks

Comment: Link added. I also did some tests by totalling CPU time by logging using Limits class in Apex trigger to ascertain if Flow time is counted as CPU limit; it still seems to be.